# Namespacing Marionette's App event aggregator events jquery-like

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, namespaces

In my Backbone Marionette App I'm filtering things in the router using 'before' and 'after' (backbone.routefilter). In order to avoid doing this in the router, I'm using App's vent to handle it somewhere else.
I have a method that add events to these handlers and everything work just fine, except if I need to remove some callbacks registered to run in the vent handler, for example:

```
// Some callback is registered to the router:before event.
App.registerRouterEventCallback.add({type: 'before', 'callback': function () { console.log("I'm Doe, John.") }});

// The URL changes and the callback is run.
App.vent.on('route:before', callback);

// In another site location, another callback is added to the events stack 
// and attached to the route:before callback: there are 2 functions registered 
// to this event now.
App.registerRouterEventCallback.add({type: 'before', 'callback': function () { console.log("I'm Doe, Josh.") }});
```

But what if the first event need to be removed? A call to App.vent.off('route:before') can't be done as it would wipe all the functions attached to this event.

The first thing I came up with is to namespace the events, so I can remove it without mess up with the other ones. But I want them to be added dynamically, not hardcoded in the router. In fact I would like to leave the router as clean as possible.

I wonder if there is something out of the box like the following:

```
// Listener for all route:before events
App.vent.on('route:before', fn);

// Listener for route:before:foo event
App.vent.on('route:before:foo', foo);
```

The idea here is to deal with it in a more jQuery-ish way, where you assign `$('#foo').on('click.foo', fn)` and have this listener removed by calling `$('#foo').off('click.foo')`.

Any ideas would be great.